# Cannot publish posts, but can create new pages

Tags: posts, pages

I am building a site on WordPress. I can't publish posts: when I attempt to do so, the site just hangs and then I get a time out page.

However, I can add new pages without a problem.

I have tried:

- Upgrading the WP build.
- Switching my theme to Twenty Ten. I still cannot publish posts.
- Deleting all plugins and the plugin folder.

None of this has resolved the issue. Should I contact my host or is this a WP issue?

Thank you for any help,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all the content generated by WordPress websites, it seems rather far-fetched that this would be a WordPress problem. I'd contact your host.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the suggestion, I did just that and it turned out to be a host-related error writing to the database.

Comment: probably not, probably there was a corruption in the sql database and the host just reverted back to an old backup of the database which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is to do as follows:

1) Back up your entire website, all files and the SQL database

2) clear the database and delete all files

3) install a fresh version of wordpress completely new.

4) try to make a post. If it works, then you are in luck, the problem is not with your host. If not, then the problem is your host.
 *(and anyways this does not at all sound like a problem with your host. It sounds like a problem with your theme or sql database got corrupted. However, if it is a problem with your host, then you should get a new host immediately because no legit web host will have problems like this.)*

5) if you confirmed you could make a post on a fresh installation of wordpress, then all you need to do is:

6) install only the theme from the backup. Nothing else.

7) verify you can make posts. If yes, then proceed to next step. If no, then there is a problem with your theme. Find the problem and fix it, and then proceed to the next step.

8) install plugins individually from within wordpress (not from your backup).

9) verify you can make posts. If yes, then congratulations, problem solved. If no, then there is a problem with one or more of your plugins. Find the problem by disabling all plugins and then enabling each plugin one by one until you find the one that is the problem.

10) congratulations, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache and disabling plugins doesnt help then you can do what i did. Most at times we copy content from another source to paste in the editor instead of just typing it in.

Some of these text include hidden encoding that the Json file cannot process so it breaks when it reads through the data you are saving so i solved the issue after trying other methods and failing by simply pasting any content i wish to paste in into a notepad then from there to the editor and thats it.

Page titles will create and safe because you didnt paste them in
but content fails cus most designers never type text into the editor but paste.

if you copy a text with horizontal lines in it and paste in editor you notice it pasted with the line which indicates the source code is held to the text, put pasting into a notpad will remove the line or image and alignments which indicates disassociation to the source code. Now its plain text and good to go. Save and enjoy!
Came in late but u may need in future